# AWS User group role FTP key

Tags: ftp, amazon-web-services

I have admin access of my AWS Console EC2 instance. I want to give limited access to some other users in my organization.

I created another group, a new user, and linked that user with that group.

Now I am using Filezilla to connect to FTP, so do my other users. For Filezilla, I am using a .pem or a .dat public key to access FTP.

**How do I generate a similar public key for my that particular new user which I just created, which can be used only by him to connect to FTP**. The reason for this is whenever I want to, I can remove access for that user by deleting the key pair or by deleting that user.

Which policy do I need to attach to my group/user for my users to be able to access FTP only, and nothing else on my AWS console.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Please read the tags **before** posting your question.